# Is it possible to pass parameter arguments in Tabpy server?

Tags: python, tableau-api, tabpy

Im pretty new in Tableau Prep Builder. I would like to use tabpy in order to run my script while creating flows in Tablau. My question: is it possible to pass parameters in python script and their arguments in tableau?
For example my parameter in python could be column name: def test(column_name). And in Tableau I want to pass column name for my python script. Is it possible?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the same functionality, but I have not found a direct way to implement passing parameters.

Looking at indirect ways, my use case seems similar to yours.  I wanted to select for particular values of a variable and run function on the filtered data.

What I ended up doing is to create a Clean step with the Add Filter feature. From there, I chose which Year I wanted to run my script on. Afterwards, my TabPy script ran.

There should be ways for other use cases, you can also create a calculated field in the Clean step and input the the parameter with the values you would want into the data to input into the TabPy script.

[image]